# Synchronized issue

Tags: java, synchronized, java-websocket

I am trying to block the concurrent access to a method , and i didn t succeeded whatever i tried.I tried to sinchronize the method by class (by using synchronized(this)  or synchronized at method level ) ,i even synchronized all methods involved , same result .

I have a connection to a websocket server, and from time to time , i reconnect .  On the @ClientEndpoint class , @OnClose method , i am instantly reconnection the session.I expected that the method which is called from @OnClose  event will wait until synchronized block from reconnectSession will end the execution.

When running this example ,you will probably see following logs :

```
 init ws connections ended 
RECCONECTING TO BINANCE WS  STARTED 
sessionWrapper instance com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa from thread Thread-21
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa started 
  session with id 0 closed with code NORMAL_CLOSURE with reason phrase 
sessionWrapper instance com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa from thread Thread-21
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa started 
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa ended 
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa ended 
RECCONECTING TO BINANCE WS  ENDED
```

I expected to see

```
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa started
RECCONECTING SESSION com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa ended
```

and not  the start twice.

I replicated the important part in this test example :

First, the main class :

```
package com.mycompany.binancereconnect;

import jakarta.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import jakarta.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author utza
 */
public class TestSynchronization {

    public List<WsSessionWrapper> wsSessions = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String BASE_SPOT_SOCKET_URL = "wss://stream.binance.com:443/ws";

    public void init() {
        try {
            for (WsSessionWrapper sessionWrapper : wsSessions) {
                WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
                if (sessionWrapper.getType().equals("SPOT")) {
                    sessionWrapper.setSession(container.connectToServer(new BinanceSpotMessageReceiver(this),
                            new URI(
                                    BASE_SPOT_SOCKET_URL)));
                }

            }
            System.out.println(" init ws connections ended ");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void reconnectSession(WsSessionWrapper sessionWrapper) {
        System.out.println("sessionWrapper instance " + sessionWrapper + " from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (sessionWrapper) {
            if (sessionWrapper.allowedToReconnect()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("RECCONECTING SESSION " + sessionWrapper + " started ");
                    try {
                        if (sessionWrapper.getSession() != null) {
                            sessionWrapper.getSession().close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    sessionWrapper.setSession(null);
                    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
                    if (sessionWrapper.getType().equals("SPOT")) {
                        sessionWrapper.setSession(container.connectToServer(new BinanceSpotMessageReceiver(this),
                                new URI(
                                        BASE_SPOT_SOCKET_URL)));
                    }
                    System.out.println("RECCONECTING SESSION " + sessionWrapper + " ended ");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void fullReconnect() {
//        aici;to also take into account no transactions on btc
        System.out.println("RECCONECTING TO BINANCE WS  STARTED ");
        for (WsSessionWrapper sessionWrapper : wsSessions) {
            reconnectSession(sessionWrapper);
        }

        System.out.println("RECCONECTING TO BINANCE WS  ENDED ");
    }

    public void reconnectSessionBySessionId(String sessionId) {
        for (WsSessionWrapper sessionWrapper : wsSessions) {
            if (sessionWrapper.getSession() != null && sessionId.equals(sessionWrapper.getSession().getId())) {
                reconnectSession(sessionWrapper);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestSynchronization testSynchronization = new TestSynchronization();
        WsSessionWrapper s1 = new WsSessionWrapper("SPOT");
        s1.setId("1");

        testSynchronization.wsSessions.add(s1);

        testSynchronization.init();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            testSynchronization.fullReconnect();
        });
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }

}
```

Second , the messageReceiver class , where onclose i attempt to reconnect :

```
package com.mycompany.binancereconnect;


import jakarta.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import jakarta.websocket.CloseReason;
import jakarta.websocket.OnClose;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 *
 * @author utza
 */

@ClientEndpoint()
public class BinanceSpotMessageReceiver {

    public BinanceSpotMessageReceiver(TestSynchronization socketService) {
        this.socketService = socketService;
    }


    
    
    private TestSynchronization socketService;

 

    private Date lastTimeTradeEventReceived = new Date();

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        if (closeReason != null) {
            System.out.println("  session with id " + session.getId() + " closed with code " + closeReason.getCloseCode() + " with reason phrase " + closeReason.getReasonPhrase());
        } else {
            System.out.println("  session with id " + session.getId() + " closed with close reason null  ");
        }
        socketService.reconnectSessionBySessionId(session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session,
            String message) throws IOException {

      

                System.out.println("received message from binance  " + message);

       

    }


}
```

And the last java class is the wrapper object :

```
package com.mycompany.binancereconnect;

import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * 
 * @author utza
 */
public class WsSessionWrapper {

    private String id;
    private Session session;
    private Date lastReconnectionTime;
    private String type;

    public WsSessionWrapper(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getLastReconnectionTime() {
        return lastReconnectionTime;
    }

    public void setLastReconnectionTime(Date lastReconnectionTime) {
        this.lastReconnectionTime = lastReconnectionTime;
    }


    //is allowed to reconnect if 1 minute passed from last reconnection
    public Boolean allowedToReconnect() {
        if (lastReconnectionTime == null || addMinutes(lastReconnectionTime, 1).compareTo(new Date()) < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Date addMinutes(Date date, int minutes) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

}
```

You might also find usefull the dependencies :

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Any help would  be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s a very large amount of code. Would you be able to create a [mre] instead, please? The question sounds interesting enough.

Comment: if you copy paste those classes and put them into a maven projects you have  it. that s the minimum required to reproduce it .All you need to change is the package

Comment: As an aside I recommend that you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. They were poorly designed and are long outdated. Use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). And use `yourInstant.plus(minutes, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` for adding minutes to it, it’s simpler and clearer to read than what you have now.

Comment: Indeed, if helps that method just check if connected in last minute (if synchronization is working as i expected) . in this case does nothing as reconnections happens somehow concurrential .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is the `onClose` method being executed when this line is reached in the `reconnectSession` method:

```
sessionWrapper.getSession().close();
```

This creates a nested or *reentrant* call to `reconnectSession`, not a concurrent one. The clue in the logs is that the same thread name is printed both times:

```
sessionWrapper instance com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa from thread Thread-21
sessionWrapper instance com.mycompany.binancereconnect.WsSessionWrapper@7c4b13aa from thread Thread-21
```

In Java, synchronized blocks are always [reentrant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) — in other words, a thread that already holds a lock can reacquire the same lock. This is a good thing: if the nested call to `reconnectSession` were to block instead, it would never become unblocked since the outer call would be unable to proceed.

One way to handle this might be to split `reconnectSession` into two methods: one that disconnects the session, and another that connects it again. The method that reestablishes the connection would only be called from the `onClose` handler, which in turn would be triggered when the method that disconnects the session calls `sessionWrapper.getSession().close()`.

Comment: Yea , that can be a solution , or to call it from a new thread . I was not fully aware of the part with access from same thread , but i had some suspicions . But still , one thing is not clear on my mind. From what i know all java threads execute synchronous operations inside the same thread. On this example , the execution of  method reconnectSession is not finished when the second execution from onClose starts. What is the logical explanation for this ? And thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a normal, synchronous method call, which stops the calling method until the method it calls returns. The first call to `reconnectSession` calls `sessionWrapper.getSession().close()`. Then, the internal implementation of `Session.close()` calls `BinanceSpotMessageReceiver.onClose()`, which calls `socketService.reconnectSessionBySessionId(session.getId())`, which calls `reconnectSession(sessionWrapper)` a second time. I would assume that the only reason this doesn't recurse infinitely is that the implementation of `Session.close()` must not call `onClose()` again if it is already closed.

Comment: If you have the logging messages print a stack trace, that might make it more clear.

Comment: Calling it from a new thread would still result in it unnecessarily closing and reconnecting a second time, and could potentially lead to a non-terminating loop of closing and reconnecting if not done carefully.

Comment: That should be fine , as i permit it to reconnect once per minute, and that s why does not recurse . But that works as long as the reconnectSession method is not called in the same time as the end i update the lastReconnectionTime marker .Related to "Just a normal, synchronous method call, which stops the calling method until the method it calls returns" : Here , u mean that when a synchronized block is called , that happens like a javascript callback ? I don t understand how things are asynchronous processed on the same thread (from my point of view at least ).

Comment: There’s nothing asynchronous or concurrent happening here. This has nothing to do with it being synchronized. Please try my suggestion of printing the stack trace.

Comment: Ok , got it , when i call session.close the OnClose will call reconnectSessionById, which will be ended before the first reconnectSession call . Now is clear , thanks for explanation